# Insert an image in a DB in blob format using a Prepared Statement

Tags: java, sql, encryption, blob, prepared-statement

I want to insert an image in a DB row in blob format, after encrypting it, using a Prepared Statement in Java. I'm using a custom encryption function and a corresponding decryption function is used on the other end to decrypt the blob back into an image (I'm not involved with the decryption part, only the encryption). The problem is that the image after the decryption is not the original one. It is a very small white image, so I assume something in my process is incorrect and I would really appreciate any feedback or thoughts. Here is the code:

```
// already existing code
...
String photo_str    // contains the photo
int id = 1;     // for this example 
byte[] blobBytes = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(photo_str);

BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(blobBytes));
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(image, type, stream);
input.set(photo_str, stream.toByteArray());   // this sets the photo_str field (String) to the second argument

// my code
byte[] blobBytes = photo_str.getBytes();
byte[] blob = CustomEncrypt(id, blobBytes);  // custom encryption function
InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(blob);

String updateString = "UPDATE MY_TABLE SET PHOTO=? WHERE ID=?";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(updateString);
ps.setBlob(1, targetStream, blob.length);
ps.setString(2, id);
int rows = ps.executeUpdate();
```

I already have the image in a String format, which is the sequence of the bytes in the byte array, as I understand, so the problem lies when I convert to byte array and then  write to input stream?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What part of this is encryption? Further, if you already have the bytes, why bother reading them into and out of an image, that at best is a no op and at worst garbles the data.

Comment: Also, don’t use `sun.misc` packages. We’ve had [`Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) since Java 8!

Comment: What makes you think it's not the *de*cryption that's the problem (you only posted tne encryption and update code)

Comment: @BoristheSpider what would you suggest instead? Now it converts from stream.toByteArray() -> String -> byte array, then encrypt to another byte array and then to an Input Stream, which is needed for the Prepared Statement. Also, this project is in Java 7, unfortunately.

Comment: @g00se I'm not involved with the decryption and there's a possibility that the problem is there. But, for the time being, I'm trying to make sure my part is not the problem, given that the decryption is correct on the other side.

Comment: There is no encryption here. Nor decryption I assume. I would suggest take the `byte[]` from Base64 decoding the image and storing in the database.

Comment: @BoristheSpider the encryption is done in CustomEncrypt()

Comment: The code as it is (barring redundancy) looks OK

Comment: If the data is different after decryption then test you code without database just encryption and decryption. Then you will see if this works at all. If this doesn't work you can do anything to fix it in your code. Ar print the `byte[]` (e.g. as hex) after encryption before saving it in the database and after loading before decryption and compare it if it is the same.